# Does onPostExecute() gets triggered even when calling asyncTask().execute().get()?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Suppose I've an AsyncTask like this :

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Boolean>{
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids){
        // Do some stuff
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    protected Void onPostExecute(Boolean b){
    // Do Some UI Changes
    }
}
```

But instead of calling *myAsyncTask().execute()*  if I call *myAsyncTask().execute().get()* ,
**For example :-**

```
boolean b = new MyAsyncTask().execute.get();
```

Will the UI changes defined in onPostExecute() method still be applied? In other words does the onPostExecute() method will still be called?

Comment: Counter question, why even bother using an async task at that point?

Comment: @tyczj not a practical problem, just thinking what will happen theoretically.

Answer (score 0):

Post execute got called even you called get on async task